# Android: After a Dialog dismissed, the activity seems lose its focus

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have an Activity with a button, click the button to show an Dialog, that works fine. But after I click the cancel button on the Dialog, the dialog disappears as dismised, but the strange thing is that:

After the dialog disappears, in the activity i have not focus.it look's like  activity has started again
this is a my source

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_credo_bussness_balance_period);

        final CustomTextviewsFromHeader header = (CustomTextviewsFromHeader) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.periodheader);
        final ImageView peridobackbtn = (ImageView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.peridobackbtn);
        final ImageView getPeriodPrice = (ImageView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.Bussperiodincomesavadatabasebtn);



        goperiod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.show();

                header.setText(periodtitle);




            }
        });

        peridobackbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        getPeriodPrice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                commentView.setText("100");
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
```

if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What have you got in your onPause() and onResume() methods? onPause() is called when the dialog appears and onResume() will be called when you dismiss it. If you're setting up (or resetting) the views in onPause() then you may need to move that to onCreate().

Comment: i have custom layout (relative layout and in this custom layout i called dialog show,i have not onResume  onPause methods @NeilS

Comment: Explain 'looks like activity has started again' - are all the views redrawn or is it just that the window has scrolled up to the top because a view at the top now has focus? Can you see that a view at the top has focus?

Comment: Do you have any code anywhere that's setting that focus?
If not, you can try setting focus to the view further down by calling requestFocus() on it from your dialog's button. But I suspect that won't scroll the screen down to the precise spot it was at, which might make for a jarring user experience.

What are you doing to make the outer view/window scrollable?